# Plone Normalizer and Letter Case

Tags: plone, archetypes

When I create Archetypes Folder, filling Title field with "My Folder", the ID (Short Name) will be normalized as "my-folder". This is good in general. But I want items to reserve the letter case, say, items from some specific folder and below, or items of specific types. What is the best practice?

Also, I find File (or Image) added by simply uploading a file named "MyFile.pdf", the ID will be "MyFile.pdf". Normalizer does nothing in this case?

Finally, uploading File named "MyFile.pdf" using collective.quickupload, the ID will be normalized as "myfile.pdf". What is the best practice here if I want reserved letter case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archetypes use the `generateNewId` method to create the id on creation. You can override this on your own types. Here is the default implementation so you can see how it is supposed to work:

```py
try:
    from plone.i18n.normalizer.interfaces import IUserPreferredURLNormalizer
    from plone.i18n.normalizer.interfaces import IURLNormalizer
    URL_NORMALIZER = True
except ImportError:
    URL_NORMALIZER = False

class BaseObject(Referenceable):

    # ...

    def generateNewId(self):
        """Suggest an id for this object.
        This id is used when automatically renaming an object after creation.
        """
        title = self.Title()
        # Can't work w/o a title
        if not title:
            return None

        # Don't do anything without the plone.i18n package
        if not URL_NORMALIZER:
            return None

        if not isinstance(title, unicode):
            charset = self.getCharset()
            title = unicode(title, charset)

        request = getattr(self, 'REQUEST', None)
        if request is not None:
            return IUserPreferredURLNormalizer(request).normalize(title)

        return queryUtility(IURLNormalizer).normalize(title)
```

As you can see, the default implementation defers to the `IUserPreferredURLNormalizer` adapter (if a request is available) and the `IURLNormalizer` utility if not; you could also provide your own implementations of those; see the [`plone.18n.normalizer` package on GitHub](https://github.com/plone/plone.i18n/tree/master/plone/i18n/normalizer) for more detail on how these work. You cannot distinguish on type or location with those though.

Dexterity content uses the `INameChooser` interface instead, for which the `plone.app.content` package [provides an implementation](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.content/blob/master/plone/app/content/namechooser.py) that uses the same `plone.i18n` infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

For regular types (folder and page) the normalization always takes place to ensure readability and consistency on your site, the file-like types (File and Image) the filename is used as-is.

Either way you can always go to the `Actions` -> `Rename` and change both its title and its id.